# Magento2: Get products by relevance

Tags: magento2, product, product-list

How can i Get a product list order by relevance  like the front office?

I want sort my search by **name**, **price** and **relevance** like the frontend.

The first two work perfectly but when $searchOrder is by relevance does not work properly. Always is the same result and different of frontoffice

```
<?php
$searchOrder  = "relevance";
$searchDirection = ($searchDir == "desc") ? SortOrder::SORT_DESC : SortOrder::SORT_ASC;

$this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->addSortOrder($searchOrder, $searchDirection);
$searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->setCurrentPage($page)->setPageSize($pageSize)->create();
$products = $this->_productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
$products = $products->getItems();
?>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you're asking?

Comment: Ok i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderBuilder $sortOrderBuilder
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->sortOrderBuilder = $sortOrderBuilder;
    ...
}

$searchOrder  = "relevance";
$searchDirection = ($searchDir == "desc") ? SortOrder::SORT_DESC : SortOrder::SORT_ASC;
$sortOrder = $this->sortOrderBuilder->setField($searchOrder)->setDirection($searchDirection)->create();
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addSortOrder($sortOrder);
```

use above way and check it.

Comment: does not work, continue ignoring when sort by relevance